# How to positioning exactly right place button with div which have background cover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put in the right place a button which is a sibling with a div which have a cover background image. Every time when I stretch the cover div (to be "responsive" in some way), I want the button to be in the right place about this cover image. I mean that the cover div image has some graphics (feathers) and I want the button to be between them every time. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

My HTML

```
<div class="cover_bgr"></div>
<div class="main">
    <a href="#"class="btn">Click</a>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.cover_bgr {
  background: url(http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/colorful_background-wide.jpg) center no-repeat;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 100;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  left: 70%;
  padding: 15x 5px;
  background-color: #2a2a2a;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}
```

My JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/onlinepch/w7v6L578/

Comment: Hi. I recommend putting your code within a **snippet** which can be found within the text editor.

Comment: Can you describe what "the right place" is?

Comment: the jsfiddle of this question https://jsfiddle.net/c0kn9aae/

Comment: What is the right place you are referring to?

Comment: We can't see the background image. My recommendation: Use percents for all the properties (include height and padding).

Comment: you'll need to add a jsfiddle with ALL your css. you element have percentages, but without knowing the elements parents and their css we can't know what the percentages mean (i.e. 100% of what? the screen, the parent, the grand parents?) Also if it's a button then use a `button` elements (or input type button) that way you wont need to bloat you css with styles to get a `a` tag to look like a `input`

Comment: I add JSFiddle, so you can see the issue.